# Compare two uchars in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to do a uchar comparison and copy, basically strcpy and strcmp on two strings, which never seems to work.

```
typedef unsigned char uchar; 
uchar a[20] = "name1";

  if(strcmp(a,"name1") == 0) 
  {    
      strcpy(a,"name2"); 
  }
```

I am never going into this if condition with this comparison.

Comment: add a null character to the end of your string `uchar a[20] = "name1\0";`

Comment: @KristerAndersson: There's already one.

Comment: @Krister I cannot change a[20]..

Comment: That should work. What is *uchar*? (was assuming `typedef unsigned char uchar;`. The problem is *uchar*!

Comment: Is this `a` exactly that or is this an example? It's not multibyte by any chance?

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: yes, i did include all header files. this is just my code snippet.

Comment: Unless @thinkcool tells us his secret about *uchar*...

Comment: With `uchar` as a `typedef` for `unsigned char`, clang warns ("warning: passing 'uchar [20]' to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]") but `"name2"` is copied into `a`.  Same result on ideone: http://ideone.com/wKFtKa

Comment: try this: `if(strcmp((char*)a,"name1") == 0) { strcpy((char*)a,"name2"); }`

Comment: @thinkcool and now, what is your compiler, and options? Again, this should work, especially for strings in the ascii range where there is no sign ambiguity. How do you test the result below the code? (eg `printf("%s\n",a);`

Comment: Some basic debugging tips:  What value does `strcmp` actually return (since it doesn't seem to be returning 0)?  Print out the characters of `a` one-by-one, including their hex values.  You may find a value that surprises you.   Don't simply say, "It doesn't work; I give up and will ask StackOverflow."

Comment: Please add your compiler to the description. I just compiled your code in VS 2012 with microsoft's compiler, and it works fine. I suppose you are either not reaching this code at all or running into some compiler-specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following link shows your code working perfectly.  I propose your error is not here but elsewhere, causing your program to never reach the code you posted.  I suggest you add some debugging statements or breakpoints before the posted code snippet to see if this happens, or at least an else statement to see if the boolean comparison fails.

http://codepad.org/XfKh2iuV

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar; 

main()
{
    uchar a[20] = "name1";

    if(strcmp(a,"name1") == 0) {    
        printf("Hello\n"); 
    }
}
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

have you put the includes on top?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```